# Odd behavior of software sources GUI in Ubuntu-based eOS (sources selected in the background)

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, elementary-os

Oddly enough, they all look unselected - I do not know that this is really true, but they look like they are not selected.

[image]

But most odd is that selecting them is impossible - as seen [HERE](https://plus.google.com/photos/109655288210924730560/albums/5942732643754418769/5942732648111471154?sqi=104613975513761463450&sqsi=a9539332-9926-473f-8087-6d819c69dbc8).

For a while this seemed to me like having something to do with this error (update duplicate source):

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-security_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

I have commented the entries involved in /etc/apt/sources.list and now `sudo apt-get update` gives no errors anymore. But the odd behavior continues.

**In fact the cause>effect relation was the other way around: it was not the duplicates that created that behavior, but with each click on that check-boxes a source was added and in this way duplicates were created.** - Eliminating them from the sources list through the GUI seemed inefficient because I was re-creating the duplicates in this way. Now I have eliminated all duplicates and the odd behavior is there. A vicious circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have check "other software". If you didn't is very likely that all those entries are there.

You can also check your `sources.list` files in case is somewhere:

```
grep security /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Edit your files with your favorite editor using root.

Answer (score 0):

That's not so much of an issue you'll find help here for, but it sounds more like a bug in this software which should be reported at the [project's bugtracker](https://launchpad.net/elementary).